# Javascript with php header redirect

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I'm working on a project that uses a `<? header('Location: http://url.com'); ?>` for redirects, and I'm very pleased with it because of the speed and the fact that it doesn't flash some intermediary URL in the address bar before redirecting. However, I now need to call my tracking software via a piece of Javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MYSCRIPT"></script>
```

Is there any way to get the best of both words? I.e. call my tracking software via the javascript and still use the php redirect? Or will I have to switch to a JS `window.location` redirect if I want to call this script?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're conflating 2 things: usually you want to do a redirect after an action (a POST for example), where as the script you want to load on pages that the user interacts with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to write the JavaScript code for your tracking in PHP and execute it before the redirect, or have a page with one of those 'you are being redirected' if you want to use Javascript.

The problem is that you cannot modify the header information after it has been sent. i.e. you can't have anything after header('Location:'); redirect.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Why would there be any need to echo anything before the header?

Comment: Thanks, I think you guys have basically confirmed what I suspected.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone You can execute PHP code, so long as it does not echo anything. Why would his tracking software need to echo anything? There is no need to display anything when tracking. I am assuming it is simply counters in a database.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone And my answer was to rewrite the JavaScript to PHP. As explained, he cannot execute JavaScript and use header location for a redirect.